# Mongoose failing with $in: [number array]

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

MongoDb documents looks like this:

```
{
"_id": {
    "$oid": "60abf5ffc4b1cb61e05bdc48"
},
"club": "FC Midtjylland",
"number": 6,
"__v": 0,
"name": "Joel Andersson"
```

}

If I create a filter in MongoDB Compass like:

```
{number: { $in: [6,11] } }
```

I get all documents with number 6 and 11

In mongose my schema is like:

```
const Player = new Schema ({
    club: { type: String, required: true },
    name: { type: String, required: true },
    number: { type: Number, required: true },
    image: { type: String, required: false },}, { collection: 'players' });
```

If I try to find the same documents in node.js with mongoose i get no results:

```
var test = "6,11"

        Player.find({number: { $in: [test] }}, function (err, player) {

          if (!player || player.length <= 0) {
            console.log('No player found!') 
            ws.send('No player found!');
         }
          else {
            //ws.send(player.number+','+player.name+','+player.image);
            console.log(player) 
          } 
          
        })
```

If I input the numbers directly in the query everything is working fine like:

```
Player.find({number: { $in: [6,11] }}, funct
```

What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Why you use a string `var test = "6,11"`  instead of an array [6,11]?

Comment: Same, nothing found.

I also tried 

var q = '{number: { $in: [6,11] } }';
and then 
Player.find(q, function (err, player) {

But same, nothing found

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
var test = [6,11]

        Player.find({number: { $in: test }}, function (err, player) {

          if (!player || player.length <= 0) {
            console.log('No player found!') 
            ws.send('No player found!');
         }
          else {
            //ws.send(player.number+','+player.name+','+player.image);
            console.log(player) 
          } 
          
        })
```

Comment: It does actually work, weird.
I tried almost the same but without $in, as documentation of mongoose states that in is not necessary.

Guess I will cast my string of numbers to a intArray then :)